# button text is blurred when css translated on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm using a button that moves up on hover. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/jmt3yk1v/. Unfortunately, button text becomes blurry when it is in the "hover" state. I've test it on different screens and the pattern seems to be that devices with `devicePixelRatio` around `1 and slightly above` seem to have the most troubles. On Retina displays, there are no issues at all.

So if you are on non retina display, you will definitively see the blurry text. What would be the fix for this problem? Should I avoid css translates or can the blurriness be mitigated.

html:

```
<a  href="/" class="btn btn-default bg inline-block"> Linky Button </a>
```

css:

```
.bg{
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #275a77 0%, #38c195 100%);
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
  .btn-default {
    border: 0;
    /* background: #2a7741; */
    padding: 11px 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}  

.inline-block{
    display: inline-block;
}


.btn:hover {
    transform: translate3d(0,-3px,0);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px #22222233;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use negative margin for animation, the blur seems to be gone

```css
.btn:hover {
    margin-top: -3px:
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px #22222233;
}
```